# Can't reset Solidity contract array variable

Tags: solidity

I'd like to reset the `players` dynamic array variable in the following contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract Lottery {
    address[] public players;
 
    function enter() public payable {
        require(msg.value > .01 ether);
        players.push(msg.sender);
    }
    
    function pickWinner() public {
        players[0].transfer(this.balance);
        players = new address[](0); // <------- HERE
    }
    
}
```

Pushing new addresses in the array works just fine, but resetting it to an empty array doesn't work: I get a `The transaction ran out of gas. Please increase the Gas Limit.` error (even when I increase the gas limit).
I've also tried `delete players` and `players.length = 0` but nothing works.

Any suggestion?

Comment: your code is working on remix. I just tested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code just works fine for a 5-element array but the longer array you get, the more gas transaction consumes.

In this case, you can increase your gas limit. There is no problem with your code.